# git: add a message that the repository has moved

Tags: git, github

I've migrated a git repository from one provider to another (github to AzureDevOps*).

Is there a way to mark the old repository as no longer in use and give a message pointing to the new location (on an attempted fetch or push).

I know that github is able to warn that a repo has been moved or renamed but is that functionality part of git itself or unique to gitub.

Comment: Don't think raw git has it.

Comment: Would a prominent update to `README` or `README.md` meet your requirements?

Comment: in raw git you can create a wrap around `git-upload-pack` for fetches and  there is a `pre-recieve` hook.

Answer (score -1):

git file is relative and if you have added remote repository named new repository in .git you will need to change remote git address in old repository.

Check old .git file if you set git remote set-url origin new_url